# Realm's DBEngine is not open source. Can I still use it?

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to use Realm in a react native application I am developing. While going through the documents, I noticed that core DBEngine is not open source (The license is Apache 2.0 though). Does it mean I can't use it without contacting realm? How does a combination of opensource and "not open-source" license work? I am a little confused here. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the FAQ it is totally free:

> Do I have to pay to use Realm?
>   No, Realm is entirely free to use, even in commercial projects.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#faq

Comment: Thanks for the help, ast